# Flutter build error after upgrading my Xcode 15.2

Tags: flutter, xcode

I upgraded my Xcode some of my App are working but this particullar app is throwing error bellow Please how can i resolve this.

```
    Xcode build done.                                           20.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/zubdev/Devs/Mobile App/Clients/Witv/witv_plus/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/zubdev/Devs/Mobile App/Clients/Witv/witv_plus/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/zubdev/Devs/Mobile App/Clients/Witv/witv_plus/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' to '/Users/zubdev/Devs/Mobile App/Clients/Witv/witv_plus/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex'
2

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->
```

Try to run on Iphone 15 pro max.